# How do I use MyBatis BlobInputStreamTypeHandler / ClobReaderTypeHandler to stream content of select request?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I need to get BLOB content and store it somewhere (let's assume it's file). BLOB content might be big, so I want to use streams to do this. On [MyBatis 'Configuration XML' page](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers) there is a list of available typehandlers. I've found there is BlobInputStreamTypeHandler which should allow me to get InputStream and that's exactly what I need. So I've specified `resultType="java.io.InputStream"` for my query in xml configuration. However I get `java.io.IOException: Closed Connection` when I try to read data from InputStream I've got after 'read from DB' method execution.
I've tried to figure it out and found that class `org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler` [is closing resultSet](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/a788a6104291d0f1e5489e74b97039cbc7facece/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/executor/resultset/DefaultResultSetHandler.java#L309) and this makes stream unreadable.

I get same exception when I try to use ClobReaderTypeHandler to get Reader from CLOB.

I'm using mybatis version 3.5.4.

How do I get Reader/InputStream from CLOB or BLOB column?
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the input stream while the session is open.

Assuming your mapper method is declared as follows...

```java
@Select("select bindata from users where id = #{id}")
InputStream selectBlob(Integer id);
```

the code that gets and reads the input stream would look something like this.

```java
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession()) {
  Mapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(Mapper.class);
  try (InputStream inputStream = mapper.selectBlob(1)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
      // use the read data
    }
  }
}
```